# Using find method in Javascript for stacking numbers

Tags: javascript, methods, ecmascript-6

I want to stack numbers using the `find()` method in JavaScript, but I've just realized I don't know how to use it. I have this table:

```
0:{categoria: "CHILE", serie: "SERVICIOS", dataCount: 1}
1:{categoria: "AUSTRALIA", serie: "CONSTRUCCION", dataCount: 1}
2:{categoria: "EEUU", serie: "SERVICIOS", dataCount: 1}
3:{categoria: "EEUU", serie: "CONSTRUCCION", dataCount: 4}
4:{categoria: "ESPAÑA", serie: "CONSTRUCCION", dataCount: 22}
5:{categoria: "ESPAÑA", serie: "SERVICIOS", dataCount: 14}
6:{categoria: "EEUU", serie: "AUTOPISTAS", dataCount: 3}
```

For each `serie` available I need to compose an array of `dataCount` values per `categoria`. The program should push a `0` if there's no `dataCount` for a set of `serie` & `categoria`. The `dataCount` arrays would look like this:

[image]

`series` are already stacked in an array

```
let series = ["SERVICIOS", "CONSTRUCCION", "AUTOPISTAS"]  
let categorias = ["CHILE", "AUSTRALIA", "EEUU", "ESPAÑA"].
```

I thought I could use something like this, but I'm unsure about how to use the `find()` method:

```
for (var serie in series) {
        var dataCount = [];
        for (var categoria in categorias) {
            var num = 0;
            if (table.find(/*Pass current serie and categoria as parameters*/)){
                num = table.find(/*Pass current serie and categoria as parameters*/);
            }
            dataCount.push(num);
        }
    }
```

Any other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: So ultimately you want 3 Arrays (AUTOPISTAS, CONSTRUCCION, SERVICIOS) and inside each of the array having 4 elements/keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method in combination with `find` by passing a *callback* function as argument for each of the methods.

The `reduce()` method applies a function against an *accumulator* and each element in the *array* (from left to right) to **reduce** it to a single value.

The algorithm consists in looking through the `series` array and for each `series` use `find` method in order to get all the values for that `series` by iterating all the categories.

```
let values = categorias.reduce(function(obj, categoria){
   let row = array.find(a => a.serie == item && a.categoria == categoria);
   obj[categoria] = row ? row.dataCount : 0
   return obj; 
}, {});
```

The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that *satisfies* the provided testing function. Otherwise *undefined* is returned.

If find method returns a value different from *undefined*, you need to assign the `dataCount` property from the result. Otherwise, use `0`.

```
obj[categoria] = row ? row.dataCount : 0
```

```js
let array = [{categoria: "CHILE", serie: "SERVICIOS", dataCount: 1}, {categoria: "AUSTRALIA", serie: "CONSTRUCCION", dataCount: 1}, {categoria: "EEUU", serie: "SERVICIOS", dataCount: 1}, {categoria: "EEUU", serie: "CONSTRUCCION", dataCount: 4}, {categoria: "ESPAÑA", serie: "CONSTRUCCION", dataCount: 22}, {categoria: "ESPAÑA", serie: "SERVICIOS", dataCount: 14}, {categoria: "EEUU", serie: "AUTOPISTAS", dataCount: 3}]

let series = ["SERVICIOS", "CONSTRUCCION", "AUTOPISTAS"].sort();
let categorias =["CHILE", "AUSTRALIA", "EEUU", "ESPAÑA"].sort();

let result = series.reduce(function(acc, item){      
  let values = categorias.reduce(function(obj, categoria){
       let row = array.find(a => a.serie == item && a.categoria == categoria);
       obj[categoria] = row ? row.dataCount : 0
       return obj; 
  }, {});
  acc[item] = values;
  return acc;
},{}); 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: And what about the AUSTRALIA, CHILE, EEUU, ESPAÑA headers?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem perfectly. If you could explain what's going on in there it would be just 200% awesome.